# How to teach Chatterbot from a custom corpus

Tags: python, chatterbot

I have been working on creating a chat bot using Gunther Cox's ChatterBot.
https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot
I am trying to create a code that will allow me to use my own YAML files and teach them to the bot. I have tried the corpus trainer and the ListTrainer functions but neither seems to work.
I tried to base my file on what the original YAML files looked like but I am unable to get it to work. I have used ListTrainer to teach the bot and it works but only if I include the list directly. The corpus trainer also works but only from the GitHub's Corpus.
I have had it sort of work once but even then it would only take one response of the many.

Here is my YAML file:

```
---
category:
- greetings
conversations:
- - hey
  - Hi
  - Hey there
  - Whats up?
  - sup
  - Greetings human
- - hi
  - Yo
  - Hey there
  - Howdy
  - Welcome
- - how are you
  - I am functioning. You?
  - Currently wishing I had a real body. Yourself?
  - I have no health or mental state so relatively I am great
  - I am doing just fine
  - I feel limited by my programming
```

Here is the code I am running:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

from chatterbot.response_selection import get_random_response

my_bot = ChatBot(name='Excalibur',read_only = True,
                 response_selection_method=get_random_response,
                 logic_adapters=[
        {
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.SpecificResponseAdapter',
            'input_text': 'empty',
            'output_text': ''
        },
        {   
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
            'default_response': 'i honestly have no idea how to respond to that',
            'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.9
        },
        {
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation'
        }

    ]
    )

trainer = ListTrainer(my_bot)

trainer.train(
    "./conversations.yml"
)

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input()

        bot_response = my_bot.get_response(user_input)

        print(bot_response)

    # Press ctrl-d on the keyboard to exit
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

Comment: define "unable to get it to work"

Comment: @user1558604 The program will run and say that it has trained the bot. This is seen by it showing the load bar. I have also tried it with a JSON file. The bar appears but when I interact with the bot it is unable to respond to anything I ask it

Comment: The first thing I notice in your code is that you have not defined a storage_adapter. I think it's necessary for the bot to work.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you are using the wrong trainer please change as follows

```
trainer = ListTrainer(my_bot)

trainer.train(
   "./conversations.yml"
)
```

with

```
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(my_bot)
 trainer.train(
   "./conversations.yml"
)
```

Explanation: ListTrainer class allows you to train from a List Data Structure while ChatterBotCorpusTrainer allows you to train from YAML or JSON data.